# Is there a way to obtain object properties after parsing a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

eg if variable jsonstring contains

```
{"prod_name":"GM","quantity":100,"price":54.5,"type":"Limit"}
```

for a code like

```
   var obj= JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

Without knowing the string content is there a way to extract the property/ value names?

Comment: `for ... in`, `Object.keys()` ...

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the object properties.

```
for ( var prop in obj ) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
        console.log( prop + ': ' + obj[prop] );
    }
}
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` isn't really necessary.

Comment: This way prevents 'walking' up the prototype chain, only checking the properties directly on the object itself.

Comment: @Andy, if they (or any third-party scripts) have extended the `Object` prototype it is necessary.

Comment: It's JSON, so I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript 1.8.5, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array of all properties found directly upon a given object.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames ( obj )
```